# Vertical space after Bibliography name

Tags: spacing, sectioning, bibliographies

I am using Bibtex and need to change (smaller size) between bibliography name and authors names. The document class is report and I am using the natbib package.

```
\documentclass[11pt,notitlepage,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,}
\usepackage{a4wide,eucal,exscale}
\usepackage{china2e,variore‌​f,acronym}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
```

Comment: Please provide an MWE

Comment: Which document class are you using? Are you using any special packages (for exampe `natbib`) to produce your bibliography? Please, as **Marco Daniel** suggested, provide all the information relevant to this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spacing between the title (**Bibliography**) and the items is exactly the same as in the other chapters.

Here is a way to reduce it, but I don't recommend doing it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum} % only for the example
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}

\lipsum[1]\nocite{*}

%%% Start of the bibliography    
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vskip40}{\vskip10}{}{} % change 10 to something else, if you prefer
\makeatother

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{jane}

\end{document}
```

This assuming you don't have any other unnumbered chapter afterwards.

The `\chapter` command relies on two macros for actually typesetting the chapter heading, `\@makechapterhead` for `\chapter` and `\@makeschapterhead` for `\chapter*`. Here are the definitions in the `report` class:

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

If you want to get rid of the space before the chapter heading *and* the space below, the best thing is to redefine them:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{-40\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 12\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{-40\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 12\p@
  }}
\makeatother
```

Adjust the `12\p@` (which is equivalent to `12pt`) to your needs.

However, this is *not* recommendable. Some space *is* needed because of the large font size used for the chapter title. If you want to reduce the space you have also to reduce the font size.

Play with the distances until you're satisfied.

### Note for `fncychap` users.

You can obtain a reduction of the spaces by

```
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\DOTIS}{40\p@}{-10\p@}{}{}
\patchcmd{\DOTI}{80\p@}{20\p@}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{50\p@}{-20\p@}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{50\p@}{-20\p@}{}{}
\makeatother
```

but I ***strongly*** advise against using such a chapter style, which is, in my opinion, one of the worst ever designed. Only Lenny is possibly worse.

Comment: Thank you for you help, but it is not what I wanted. Generally TEX using too much free space around chapternames, which I don't like. I have already sorted out how to change space up any chaptername by using usepackage etoolbox and this commands \makeatletter \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{50\p@}{-40pt}{}{} \patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{50\p@}{-40pt}{}{}  \makeatother Now I'm trying to get rid of too much emty space below chapternames, for table of contents I used this one \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{-2cm}} for chapters and chapters* simply \vspace{-2cm} but what about Bibliography?

Comment: Sorry, but again wrong. I cannot use this at all. I'm using also fncychap package and it doesn't work with that. Moreover, I have already finished most of the thesis and can't change everything by this way. There must be a simpler way how to do it, the only thing I need is to put smaller gap after bibliography name. I have already sorted out table of contents by adding the only link \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{-2cm}}. is there anythingl like this for Bibliography?

Comment: @Jane: Comments like yours shows -- your are too lazy to provide a MWE but forces the correct answer. That is really a shame.

Comment: Well, I'm not lazy to provide a MWE..I don't even know what it is....I guess to put part of my work here..Again, I don't know how to do it....

Comment: @Jane How do you think we can guess what packages you're using?

Comment: Please, add to your original question where it's more easily looked at. Consider also that the Glenn style is, in my opinion, the worst style around.

Comment: @egreg: Thank you for you help. I appreciate it very much, but it is not helpful either. It works only for chapters not for bibliography and table of contents.

Comment: @Jane In my test it does.

Comment: @ egreg: I'm sorry I have already found out that it's working. It was my fault I didn't write it well. Thanks for your help. However, I can see that Glenn style drives you crazy. You made me nervous with this so I decided to change it in case I will find something better looking. I want something extra original, it will be hard to get it. Anyway, I will try.